# How to upload a Photo and save it into website using Python Flask

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am having trouble allowing users to upload a photo into my website and have it save to a folder so that the photo could be used later on. My goal is to have my program guess the shape that was submitted.

I so far have the html code in which allows a user to upload a photo onto my website but when the user submits it, it goes no where.
HTML:

```html
<div class="w3-third">
    Your image: <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: File uploads are a server-side feature, so this can not be achieved in HTML alone.  You tagged this pythonanywhere; which python framework are you using to build the site?

Comment: I am using flask! So I am now working off of the pythonanywhere tutorials to create a webapp but they only show how to have users comment and have that comment saved in your sql table but not how to do it with photos! @v25

Comment: See the [official docs on files uploads](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) for information on how to implement this on the server side.

Comment: I will check it out, thank you @v25